# Magento email cron not working in Godaddy Hosted site

Tags: magento-1.9, cron, order-email, server-setup

I have my client's site hosted at Godaddy Server.

Magento version: CE-1.9.2.4.

Now I have setup cron to autorun every 1 minute like below:

```
/web/cgi-bin/php5 /home/acmeimpex/public_html/rootfolder.com.au/cron.php
```

But this cron isn't running and I ain't getting any New Order emails.

Can anyone suggest something ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be godaddy server has php installed in some other directory than `cgi-bin`.

So,try running cron like bellow.

```
wget -q -O /dev/null http://www.webname.com/cron.php
```