# Unable to set up cron job on GoDaddy hosting

Tags: magento-2.0, cron, indexing, indexer

I am trying to set up my indexer using GoDaddy hosting with cPanel. The indexer is not refreshed and asks me to check that the cron job is running. How do I set up the cron job?

Comment: You can see here syntax for cron job. http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/113391/magento-email-cron-not-working-in-godaddy-hosted-site     And you can set log in cron so you can see if your cron is working or not

Answer (score 0):

Maybe there is error in syntax. please check syntax first.

This article might be helpful

```
https://in.godaddy.com/help/create-cron-jobs-16086
```

or you can call or chat with godaddy support team to help you.